# Creating a public S3 bucket with AWS SAM / Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am having issues creating public buckets as AWS SAM recently deprecated the use of:

```
AccessControl: PublicRead
```

on AWS S3 Bucket resources.

Example template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  public-bucket-issues

################################
# Parameters
################################

Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket name
    Type: String
    Default: 'my-test-public-bucket-abc123'

################################
# Resources
################################

Resources:

  PublicBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      # Set up for public website hosting
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
        ErrorDocument: index.html
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          - AllowedOrigins:
              - "*"
              - !Ref BucketName
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE
              - HEAD
            AllowedHeaders:
              - "*"
            MaxAge: 3000
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerPreferred
```

This configuration *works* when you deploy it, but I get the following linting errors (breaking all CICD):

```
W3045 Consider using AWS::S3::BucketPolicy instead of AccessControl
/path/to/template.yaml:27:7

Error: Linting failed. At least one linting rule was matched to the provided template.
```

As you can see from the [Cloud Formation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-accesscontrol), this is indeed deprecated:
[image: ACL docs]

The SAM Linter is so kind to give me a hint that I should use a bucket policy! So I add the bucket policy to my bucket as follows:

```yaml
  PublicBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref PublicBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*"
```

This gives me a permissions error when I deploy when it tries to create the policy (even through I am an administrator on the account with no explicit DENYs on any user policies):

```
CREATE_FAILED                                      AWS::S3::BucketPolicy                              PublicBucketPolicy                              Resource handler returned message: "Access       
                                                                                                                                                         Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request... HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
```

So, CloudFormation has deprecated the `AccessControl` attribute on the S3 bucket, but not given us clear instructions on how to properly setup a public bucket. They point to a guide that talks about how ACLs work, but not how to enable them on a bucket via CloudFormation.  Any help on how I can set this up would be very helpful.  I would like to be able to setup public website hosting via cloudfront but am having issues setting up a policy as directed!

Comment: `CREATE_FAILED` the CF event usually contains details whay/why failed, could you provide these too plz?

Comment: All it said was access denied. I wasn't able to find any other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the Public Access configuration of your bucket ([AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html)). I had the same issue on terraform until I did that.

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-s3-bucket--examples), it should look like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls       : true
        BlockPublicPolicy     : false # Will allow the creation of the policy
        IgnorePublicAcls      : true
        RestrictPublicBuckets : false # Will allow non-AWS entities to read what is inside the bucket
```

Also, here the terraform version of this for reference:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public_image_bucket_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.public_image_bucket.id

  block_public_acls  = true
  ignore_public_acls = true
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great find. If I set only `BlockPublicPolicy` and `RestrictPublicBuckets` to false and tried to deploy the policy CloudFormation would just hang. If I set all of them to false it went through. Super strange behavior. Thanks for the answer.